# Apache openwebbeans with JDK17

Tags: java-17, openwebbeans, openjdk-17

I am upgrading openwebbeans project from  openJDK12 to OpenJDK17 . currently webeans version is being used 2.0.10 . When upgrading application is not coming up. Is there any apachewebbeans version supporting java 17  and in near future any plan?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** OWB-2.0.27 is compatible to JDK17 without having to change the xbean- libraries.

According to this site (https://openwebbeans.apache.org/download.html) OWB-2.0.x should support Java17.

> It uses a shaded version of ASM-9 (Java17 support) for building our proxies and requires JavaSE 8 as minimum version.

But i have also problems getting the OWB-2.0.26 version to run with JDK17 because of the used xbean-asm9-shaded lib which only supports java up to version 16.

Comment: I somehow managed to get that working after upgrading webbeans to 2.0.26 and jersey to 2.35 and bean-finder-shaded and xbean-asm9-shaded to  4.20. but still had to use lot of --add-exports and --add-opens .

Comment: @grv any chance you could list all of those options

Comment: i used following options  --add-exports=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED